# Carbon footprint calculation method

Tags: android, calculator, equation

I'm currently doing my final year project. The end product of this project is to develop an Android application that can be used by an individual to track the amount of carbon gas emitted through daily activities and consumption. I'm having trouble in searching and understanding the method use for calculation. Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to get the user to input their daily food waste, etc and use a formula to calculate it. A quick search on google brought me to https://www3.epa.gov/carbon-footprint-calculator/ which has an excelsheet with the various formulas you can download on that page.

As for how the formula or its constants are derived, I have no clue myself.

Comment: oh, thank you very much for the response. have a great day ahead !